# What is the best way to randomly pick numbers from 1 to 10 without repeating one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an efficient way to unwrap an integer into random, unique numbers?

I want `10` to become `3 4 6 1 0 2 5 7 8 9`.

I tried [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/7dp3E/)  ...but before pushing values into arrays and going loop crazy I thought maybe there was a better way.

**EDIT:**

**HERE IS MY NEW [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4eR7L/4/) AND FUNCTION:**

```
function uniqueDigits(x){
    y = [];
    z = [];
    while(x > 0) {    
        y.push(x);
        x--;
    } 
    while(y.length > 0){
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*y.length);
        var u = y[r]
        y.splice(r, 1);
        z.push(u-1);
    }         
    return z;
}

uniqueDigits(4) //['2', '3', '0', '1']
```

**EDIT:**

**AND HERE IS ANOTHER [OPTION](http://jsfiddle.net/46yaZ/3/):**

```
function uniqueNum(x){
  z = y = x;
  var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * x);

  while ( x%r%2 == 0 ) {
    r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * x);
  }

  while( x>0 ){
    y = y - r     
    if(y<0){ 
      var n = y; 
      y = z + n 
    }   
    $('p').append(y);
    x--
   }    
} uniqueNum(4);//['2', '3', '0', '1']
```

**OR [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/aQMFG/1/) one too**

Ok I'm done.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Its not a duplicate of the first one.  The output cannot repeat

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the other either, Look this repeats the same integers:  http://jsfiddle.net/ecLHN/

Comment: @Squirrl, are you pressing "Run" repeatedly in jsfiddle? If yes, then of course it can repeat, but it's nothing wrong with the code :-)

Comment: @Squirrl although your solution can be derived from the linked posts I think your question is unique enough for a tailored answer and have voted to reopen (FYI there are 2 reopen votes at the moment). Sorry to have voted to close so quickly.

Comment: Thanks Wesley.  I thought perhaps there was a particularly elegant way to solve such a seemingly simple task.

Comment: for pseudo randomized array (not really random): `var pseudoRandomArray = Array.apply(null, { length: 10 }).map(Number.call, Number).sort(function() {
    return Math.random() > Math.random();
});`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aQMFG/ Works.  Not sure if it's the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for all number in the range, try

```
var x = 10,
    array = [];
for (var y = 0; y < x; y++) {
    array.push(y);
}
while (array.length) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    $('p').append(array.splice(random, 1));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VshU8/)

---

Another way using an array is

```
var x = 10,
    array = [];
//used for counting the loop for performance testing - remove it
var counter = 0;
for (var y = 0; y < x;) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
    if ($.inArray(random, array) == -1) {
        $('p').append(random);
        array.push(random);
        y++;        
    }
    //for test
    counter++;
}
console.log(counter)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M7rfG/1/) - but the loop executes too many times

Comment: @Arun Wow I came to the same conclusion u gave me hours ago.  Haha Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To be more efficient, I would write the range, and then shuffle it like using

> The de-facto unbiased shuffle algorithm is the Fisher-Yates (aka
>   Knuth) Shuffle.

from [How to randomize (shuffle) a javascript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) answer.

So it would be:

```
var x = 10;
var range = [];
for (var y = 0; y < x; y++) {
    range.push(y);
}
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length
    , temporaryValue
    , randomIndex
    ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
}
shuffle(range);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it this way:

```
function getRandomNonRepeatedInt(limit)
{
    var array = [], result = "";
    for (var y = 0; y <= limit-1; array.push(y), y++);
    while (array.length) result = result + array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1)[0];
    return result;
}
```

Sorry about the obfuscation... :-)

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricis/GLp5H/)